# Docker on Windows 10. E: Unable to locate package. Returns non-zero code 123

Tags: python, windows, docker, docker-compose

I am having some issues with docker on Windows 10. Would welcome any help.

I've recently switched from OSX to Windows as I have a new company laptop. When I run docker i'm met with the below error. (Our website is predominantly build in Python).

```
E: Unable to locate package build-essential
E: Unable to locate package python-dev
E: Unable to locate package python-setuptools
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
E: Unable to locate package libpq-dev
E: Unable to locate package graphviz
E: Unable to locate package libgraphviz-dev
E: Unable to locate package pkg-config
E: Unable to locate package libjpeg-dev
    The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && cat /srv/src/packages.txt | xargs apt-get -y --force-yes install     && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*' returned a non-zero code: 123
```

I cloned our GitHub repo, used the Docker Quickstart Terminal to navigate to the correctly directory and used the ./run command. On OSX it would build the image no problem and would not fail. This error has only occurred on Windows. I've tried this on a Dell XPS and a Surface and I get the same error, so I am pretty confident it's an issue with the OS and Docker.

I've tried installing packages using Cygwin to no avail. And also downloading Python directly to the O/S. Same error.

I'm not an advanced web developer, but I make edits to our website. Our tech guy is away so I'd really appreciate any help in getting this to work - if at all possible! Have tried searching but can't find anything relating to Docker on Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get successful output information from the `apt-get update` step?

Comment: Apologies, I should have included that. Yes I did get successful output information. 

This error appears after the script has been running for approx. 3 minutes after the following:


Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages [7589 kB]
Fetched 21.7 MB in 48s (446 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...

Comment: As a temp fix, try add the package names directly to the Dockerfile and see if it works. `apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential python-dev ....`

Comment: Thank you. Have tried this, script runs for longer but still presents the same error message. Bizarre.

Comment: Probably up have a DNS issue.